# C++ make a variable type depend on user input

Tags: c++, arrays

I want a function that creates an array for testing purposes:

- The idea es to make the user select the type of elements the array will contain (int, float, double).
- Then it has to return an array of the selected type and **main** has to use it as a parameter. I understand this is done using a **void pointer**, but I would be glad if someone could provide me an example.

So this would be the example code

```
    **type** vector()
    {
    int t;
    int op;
    cout << "Size: \n";
    cin >> t;
    **type** * v = new **type**[t]
    cout << "Select type\n";
    cin >> op;
    switch(op) {
     case 0:
            // Create the array with the selected option...
            return * v;
     case 1:
            // Create the array with the selected option...
            return * v;
     default:
            // Other stuff;
               }
    }
```

So the question would be what type of function should I use, and also what type of dynamic variable should I declare as v.

And also how to use it later on other functions once correctly done.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to _do_ with an array of unknown type in main?

Comment: I need to test the compile run and wall times depending on different factors. One of them is the variable type. I study mathematics and we are learning about memory usage and using logarithms for working with integers in case it is needed. The idea is to use main for testing algorithmns like quicksort, mergesort...

Comment: But it seems the best way is to use different functions for each types.

Comment: Yes, although you can use templates to avoid having to write those different functions separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is that you **cannot**, because data types need to be specifically declared at compile time.

If you can use boost libraries,

```
boost::variant<int,float,double> vec;
```

can suit your needs.

You cannot use `union` because `std::vector` is not a *POD* (Plain Old Datatype).

EDIT:

As @Rob pointed out:

> Void pointers need to be converted into a pointer to something else -
>   at compile time - before they can be used that way. So the answer is
>   still "cannot" use void pointers to make a variable data type.

Comment: Okay, So to both questions no?

Comment: I thought the second one was possible.

Comment: void pointers need to be converted into a pointer to something else - at compile time - before they can be used that way.   So the answer is still "cannot".

Comment: I don't have sufficient knowledge about void pointers. Thanks for clearing the confusion! :) @Rob

Comment: _"So the answer is still 'cannot'."_ Total nonsense. How do you think `boost::variant` works??

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Rob meant that we *cannot* use void pointers to emulate a *variable data type*. Sorry for the confusion. I'll edit it now.

Comment: @ShauryaChats: I know what he meant and I stand by my response. The trick is to interpret the pointer after-the-fact, which is certainly not impossible.

Comment: Oh. So, it *is* possible to emulate a variable data type using void pointers, is what you are saying. Can you please give an example of this so that I can add this in my answer? @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Comment: @ShauryaChats: I'm sure you can manage it yourself :) Think two "out parameters", one having `void*` and the other having some `enum ErasedType` that you define yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Since C++ is a statically typed language, you cannot really do this in a simple way. You cannot determine types at runtime, these are fixed as soon your program has been compiled.

The closest thing you can get for your case IMHO, is using something like a [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/variant.html) or [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/any.html).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should re-think your design.

Rather than trying to write a function that returns an array of user-defined type to test. I would instead call a different test function depending on the user choice.

The test function can be templated to avoid code duplication:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void doTest(unsigned size) {

    std::vector<T> data(size);

    // Do the actual test on the data...
}


int main() {
    unsigned size;
    std::cout << "Size: \n";
    std::cin >> size;

    int op;
    std::cout << "Select type\n";
    std::cin >> op;
    switch(op) {
     case 0:
         doTest<int>(size);
         break;
     case 1:
     default:
         doTest<float>(size);
    }
}
```

If you really want to return your array from a function you could wrap it in a polymorphic type. But to actually do anything with the array you would need to call a virtual method on the polymorphic type so I don't see how it buys you anything over calling a test function directly.

Answer (score 0):

it can be done using `void*` but in that case you need to do type casting yourself (as pointed out by @Rob) i.e. using `reinterpret_cast` operator or similar. Here is a simple example with void*

```
 void* vector(){
    int t;
    int op;
    cout << "Size: \n";
    cin >> t;
    cout << "Select type\n";
    cin >> op;
    switch(op) {
     case 0:
           // Create the array with the selected option...
            return  reinterpret_cast<void*>(new int[t]);

     case 1:
            // Create the array with the selected option...
            return  reinterpret_cast<void*>(new double[t]);

     default:
            // Other stuff;
            return  reinterpret_cast<void*>(new float[t]);
       }
    }
```

Note: you can look at working of `malloc()` function, it always returns `void*` to allocated memory and you have to type cast it yourself e.g `malloc(sizeof(int)*t)`

Comment: What is the OP supposed to do with the result of this function?

Comment: yes you are rite. I won't be useful to use void*  it would be better to use design patter like factory pattern here and pass OP as argument. Better to re-think the design.

Comment: An `enum` "out parameter" indicating the result type would do